# how to toggle visibility of a div in knockout using jQuery ajax post request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Here is the JS that I coded to post the ajax request to the controller. For some reason the jquery version of hide() and show() do not work with knockout, and this is probably due the script positioning. However, when I rearrange jQuery script to the bottom of the page, the ajax post somehow works and posts the data to the controller but like I said, the hide() and show() of jQuery do not work.

If I move jQuery script tag above bootstrap and other scrips, the hide() and show() work, but the ajax post to the controller comes out as null. 
I have spent hours trying to figure out the placement of the scripts, it apparently makes no sense to me. If someone can explain to me what is going on, I would really appreciate it.

Here is Reservation.Js :-

```
        var ReservationViewModel = function () {
       var self = this;
       self.formDiv = ko.observable(true);
       self.responseDiv = ko.observable(false);

       self.SubmitForm = function () {
            self.Name = $('#name').val();
            self.Age = $('#age').val();
            self.DateOfBirth = $('#dob').val();
            self.NoOfPassengers = $('#nop').val();
            self.NoOfChildPassengers= $('#nocp').val();
            self.Phone = $('#phone').val();
            self.Email = $('#email').val();
            self.DepartureDate = $('#depDate').val();
            self.ReturnDate = $('#retDate').val();
            self.Hotel = $('#hotel').val();
            self.Description = $('#message').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Reservation/Insert',
                contentType: "application/json",
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                data: ko.toJSON(self),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success = true) {
                        self.responseDiv(true);
                        self.formDiv(false);
                    } else {
                        alert("Your form could not be submitted.");

                    }
                 }

            });

        }

    }

   $(document).ready(function () {

        var viewModel = new ReservationViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('dataSection'));
 });
```

Here is the div on the index page :-

```
 <div id="dataSection">
            <div id="responseDiv" data-bind="visible : responseDiv">
                <p>We have received your reservation request. Someone from our office will get in touch with you soon based on the information your provided. </p>
            </div>
            <div id="formDiv" data-bind="visible : formDiv">
                <form asp-action="Insert" asp-controller="Reservation" method="post">
                    <div class="row animate-box">

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" asp-for="Name" id="name">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" asp-for="Age" id="age">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DOB" asp-for="DateOfBirth" id="dob">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No of Passengers" asp-for="NoOfPassengers" id="nop">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="NoOfPassengers" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No of Child Passengers" asp-for="NoOfChildPassengers" id="nocp">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="NoOfChildPassengers" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" asp-for="Phone" id="phone">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" asp-for="Email" id="email">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Departure Date" asp-for="DepartureDate" id="depDate">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="DepartureDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Return Date" asp-for="ReturnDate" id="retDate">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="ReturnDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What type of Hotel" asp-for="Hotel" id="hotel">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Hotel" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message" asp-for="Description" id="message"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:function(){ SubmitForm();}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's how the scrips are positioned on the Layout page :

```
     <!-- Knockout JS -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/js/knockout.js'></script>

<!-- FOR IE9 below -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<!-- Main JS -->

<div id="fh5co-wrapper">
    <div id="fh5co-page">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_MenuHeader.cshtml")
        <!-- end:header-top -->

        @RenderSection("banner", true)

        @if (IsSectionDefined("flightWidget"))
        {
            @RenderSection("flightWidget")
        }
        else
        { }


        @RenderSection("travelPackages", false)
        @RenderSection("bookings", false)
        @RenderSection("upcoming", false)
        @RenderSection("visa", false)
        @RenderSection("services", false)


        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml")

    </div>
    <!-- END fh5co-page -->
</div>
<!-- END fh5co-wrapper -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Easing -->
<script src="~/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- Modernizr JS -->
<script src="~/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Waypoints -->
<script src="~/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/sticky.js"></script>
<!-- Stellar -->
<script src="~/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<!-- Superfish -->
<script src="~/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/superfish.js"></script>
<!-- Magnific Popup -->
<script src="~/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>
<!-- Date Picker -->
<script src="~/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- CS Select -->
<script src="~/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/selectFx.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/main.js"></script>
```

Here is the controller function :

```
         public ContentResult Insert(Reservation reservation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.Add(reservation);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = true }),
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = false }),
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the jQuery calls to `hide` and `show` in here, but you should not be using them because your contract with Knockout is that it controls the DOM and you manipulate the viewmodel.

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html

Comment: @JasonSpake I tried to use the visible bindings as you can see in my code `formDiv` and `responseDiv`, however, they do not work, they do not hide or show my div.

Comment: @RoyJ I tried those and replaced them with knockout visible bindings, however, neither go through. Like I mentioned earlier, I hide and show were only working when the jquery script tag was added before my script. However, that caused my knockout  post values to arrive null at the controller. But when jquery was declared after, the knockout post worked but jquery hide and show failed.

Comment: It seems unlikely that knockout's visible binding doesn't work. I'm pretty sure someone would have noticed. Where do you call `ko.applyBindings`?

Comment: @JasonSpake In reservation.js, code display here on SO is scroll-able, scroll on it and check.

Comment: When I paste your code into a jsfiddle the visible binding seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @JasonSpake I thank you for you time and patience in my questions, can you also check if the scripts are positioned correctly , under the heading `Here's how the scrips are positioned on the Layout page `